# Wordpress - Run function without leaving current page

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a function in my functions.php as follows:-

```
function favourite_job() {

    if (!empty($_GET['job_fav'])) {
        $job_id = $_GET['job_fav'];
        $prev_id = get_field('favourite_jobs', 'user_'.get_current_user_id());
        if($prev_id != '') {
            $update_favourite = $prev_id .','.$job_id;
        } else {
            $update_favourite = $job_id; 
        }
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'favourite_jobs', $update_favourite);
}
if (!empty($_GET['job_fav'])) {
add_filter('init' ,'favourite_job');
}
```

This basically updates a user with a 'favourite job' ID which is all working fine.

On the markup I have the following:-

```
<a href="favourite_job/?job_fav=<?php the_ID(); ?>"><div class="job-single-favourite icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>"></div></a>
```

Which loads a separate page and runs the function. I basically want to run this function without leaving the current page.

Not sure if it would need to reload the current page or not...

basically what I intend to do is the page will get all the favourite jobs which would be like; '123, 234, 345', then it will loop each of the job ID's and mark the job as favourite if it's in the array.

But for now I just need to load the same page and run the function, thanks in advance.

Comment: its better to use form with POST method, or even better to do request via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to have the page reload after the user inserts/updates the database:

```
    function favourite_job() {

        if (!empty($_GET['job_fav'])) {
            $job_id = $_GET['job_fav'];
            $prev_id = get_field('favourite_jobs', 'user_'.get_current_user_id());
            if($prev_id != '') {
                $update_favourite = $prev_id .','.$job_id;
            } else {
                $update_favourite = $job_id; 
            }
        }

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        update_user_meta($user_id, 'favourite_jobs', $update_favourite);
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['job_fav'])) {
    add_filter('init' ,'favourite_job');
    }
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: Okay @SaucedApples - How can I run this function and reload the same page on click of the link?